# Merge n number of json file into one json file in groovy language

Tags: groovy, scripting, jenkins-groovy

hello below is my groovy script in that script at a time only two json file is merged in to one but I need to merge n number of file

this is my groovy script

```
json_file_link_1 = ''  // here u want to give json file link
json_file_linl_2 = '' // here u want to give json file link
Merge_json_file_link = "" //here u want to give where u store your merged two json file
def allContentFile = new File(Merge_json_file_link)
def fileLocations = [json_file_link_1,json_file_link_2]
fileLocations.each{ allContentFile.append(new File(it).getText()) }
print("merged json is generrated")
```

in this groovy only two json file is merged i want to merged n number json file at a time

can anyone please share some solution how can i do this

Comment: Can we assume, that your actual problem is to _find_ the files you want to join?  E.g. you have to join files in a directory? Or what would `json_file_linm_3` be?

Comment: i want to join or merge N number of file in one json file Eg. i have 3 json file so when i run this groovy then i give all the 3 file path and then its generate merged json file into one

Comment: You are doing that - add the additional files to `fileLocations` and it should work to whatever degree it is working right now. Your example is not complete and therefor it's not clear (to me) what you are actually struggling with. Is the result not merged in the way you like it (most likely, because you just bang the files together - but without the content of the files we can not tell).